# Uploading excel file in Python tkinter and print as dataframe

Tags: python, file, user-interface, tkinter, upload

I want to create an interface that contains uploding file feature. I mean, when I click "upload the file" button, a pop up will occur and I will chose regarding excel file. After that I should take it as a dataframe. I tried some solutions but could not find the actual result. My solution is not very efficient btw. As may seen I try to get path and then try to get dataframe.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from datetime import date
import time
from datetime import timedelta
import os, os.path
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, read_excel, merge, read_csv
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import tkinter.filedialog as fdialog
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, read_excel, merge, read_csv
.
.
.

class Page2(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="", bg="white")
        button_2=tk.Button(self,text="Om Creation", width=10,height=3 ,fg="white",bg="blue",font=("Arial",10), command=self.OMcreat).place(x=750,y=400)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        button_4=tk.Button(self,text="upload file", width=12,height=3,fg="white",bg="blue",font=("Arial",10), command=self.upload).place(x=350,y=450)




    def upload(self):
        print("uploaded")        

        #root.directory = tkFileDialog.askdirectory()
        #print (root.directory)



        filem1 = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Template files", "*.tplate"),
                                           ("HTML files", "*.html;*.htm"),
                                           ("All files", "*.*") ))


        print(filem1)

        file2=filem1.name


        filem3=str(file2)
        print(filem3)
        filem4=filem3.replace("/", "\\")
        print(filem4)
        df_cities=read_excel(filem4)
        print(df_cities.head())
        reportname=df_cities.at[1,'Report_Name']
        print(reportname)
        df_cities.head()
        df=open(file2)
        df_excelim=read_excel(filem1)
```

error is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-14-88767c64d414>", line 118, in upload
    file2=filem1.name
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

askopenfilename returns a string containing the file path.  The string doesn't have a method or attribute called "name".  You could write:

```
file2 = filem1
```

Comment: As an aside, you could use the os.path library to format the filename for prior to "df_cities=read_excel(filem4)".  This will allow your code to be independent of the forward slash / backslash difference between Windows and Linux.

Comment: thank you very much, I got the point totally and fixed my issue very easily :)))